# Displaying array of objects dynamically in table columns - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, grid-layout

I am attempting to create an appointment slot selection grid. I have all the appointments grouped into dates. I want to display the array of Objects below as a clickable grid. I have everything I need but I'm having difficulty displaying it in columns. My current output:
[image]

As you can see it is displaying the correct appointments next to the correct date header however its adding the next one in the same row and so on. I want each date and its corresponding appointments to be displayed in separate columns. Date header at the top with appointments listed below. I'm just using a main.js file and an index.html file.

Grouped appointment slots array below looks something like this:

```
2020-09-25: [{0:{AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-25T13:00:00Z"}}]
2020-09-28: [{0:{AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-28T08:00:00Z"}},{1:{AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-28T10:30:00Z"}}, {2:{AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-28T11:00:00Z"}}]
2020-09-29: [{0:{AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-29T08:00:00Z"}},{1:{AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-29T09:00:00Z"}}, {2:{AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-29T11:00:00Z"}}]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```js
let result = await response.json();
let groupedAppointments = {}

result.forEach((item) => {
    const date = item.AppointmentDateTime.split('T')[0]
    if (groupedAppointments[date]) {
        groupedAppointments[date].push(item);
    } else {
        groupedAppointments[date] = [item];
    }
})


var grid = clickableGrid(groupedAppointments, groupedAppointments, function(el, item) {
    console.log("You clicked on element:", el);
    selectedAppointment = item.AppointmentDateTime;
    console.log(selectedAppointment);
    el.className = 'clicked';
    if (lastClicked) lastClicked.className = '';
    lastClicked = el;
});

document.getElementById("clickable-grid").appendChild(grid);
```

```js
function clickableGrid(groupedAppointments, index, callback) {
    var i = 0;
    var grid = document.createElement('table');

    grid.className = 'grid';

    Object.keys(groupedAppointments).forEach((item) => {

        var days = groupedAppointments[item];
        var tableRowHeader = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        var th = tableRowHeader.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));
        th.innerHTML = item;

        days.forEach((item) => {

            var tr = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
            //var rowHeader = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th'))
            var cell = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
            //rowHeader.innerHTML = item.SlotName;
            cell.innerHTML = item.AppointmentDateTime;
            cell.addEventListener('click', (function(el, item) {
                return function() {
                    callback(el, item);
                }
            })(cell, item), false);
        })

    })

    return grid;
}
```

I hope this is enough detail. Any questions just ask. All help greatly appreciated.

updated output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, you want the information displayed in a table (...): Use a table?!? :)  (i.e. NOT grid...)

Comment: Later on, when displaying the items, would you remove the date from them?

Comment: Yes when displaying the items I will be displaying just the time "9:00 AM" in this format. I want it to function as a clickable grid I just thought this was the best route to go for having the selection functionality I wanted.

Comment: I'd put the clickable desirability/requirement somewhere at the top of the question.
I've done something similar with divs and divs of divs and divs of divs of divs and so on...
Got messy fast.
Plus, I wanted to shift left/right depending if day is "Hebrew"/"Secular" (Hebrew days start and end at sundown vs. Secular - at midnight, with an option for calendars with days at sunrise...).

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the desired result, as it gets lost in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create a `tr` for each appointment.

You need two loops. One loop creates the header row with all the dates.

Then you loop over the array indexes to create the data rows. Within that, you have a nested loop for each date, filling in that column in the row. Since dates will have different numbers of appointments, you need to check if the current date has that many appointments. If it is you fill in the cell, otherwise you leave it empty.

```js
function clickableGrid(groupedAppointments, callback) {
  var i = 0;
  var grid = document.createElement('table');

  grid.className = 'grid';
  var longest = 0;
  var headerRow = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
  Object.entries(groupedAppointments).forEach(([item, day]) => {
    if (day.length > longest) {
      longest = day.length;
    }
    var th = headerRow.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));
    th.innerHTML = item;
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < longest; i++) {
    var tr = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
    Object.values(groupedAppointments).forEach(item => {
      var cell = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
      if (i < item.length) {
        let time = item[i].AppointmentDateTime.split('T')[1].split('Z')[0];
        cell.innerHTML = time;
        cell.addEventListener('click', (function(el, item) {
          return function() {
            callback(el, item);
          }
        })(cell, item[i]), false);
      }
    });
  }

  return grid;
}

var data = {
  "2020-09-25": [{
    AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-25T13:00:00Z"
  }],
  "2020-09-28": [{
    AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-28T08:00:00Z"
  }, {
    AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-28T10:30:00Z"
  }, {
    AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-28T11:00:00Z"
  }],
  "2020-09-29": [{
    AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-29T08:00:00Z"
  }, {
    AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-29T09:00:00Z"
  }, {
    AppointmentDateTime: "2020-09-29T11:00:00Z"
  }]
};

document.body.appendChild(clickableGrid(data, function(cell, date) {
  console.log("You clicked on " + date.AppointmentDateTime);
}));
```

Comment: The above approach is close however its still displaying in rows for some reason and not as columns. I've added a screenshot in my answer of the updated output

Comment: I've updated the answer to transpose the grid items.

Comment: Again doesn't quite work. This has been the frustrating part for me. Managing to arrange them in underneath each header. updated output for most recent response.

Comment: You can see the second attempt underneath updated output is further off from the first responses output you gave

Comment: I needed to create the cell inside the inner `forEach()`.

Comment: This solves the problem! Thanks for all your help. The data isnt positioned exactly under each column but im guessing I can sort this by fixing the column width so when the first column only has 1 appointment it wont cause the rest of the data in the table to slip underneath the first column.

Comment: That's not happening in my snippet.

Comment: Make sure you create the cell before the `if`, not inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your table is all over the place, you create 2 table rows when actually you need to use only one for every date (with both the th and the appointments) and you only need to go to a new row when a new date is presented.
I've changed some namings to be more precise (item doesn't tell a lot about what it is, plus it gets confusing when you use the same name for different params).
My commented-out lines are marked with a `*`.

```
function clickableGrid(groupedAppointments, index, callback) {
    var i = 0;
    var grid = document.createElement('table');

    grid.className = 'grid';

    Object.keys(groupedAppointments).forEach((date) => {

        //*var days = groupedAppointments[key]; --> since you don't copy and just refferencing a memory slot
        var tr = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr')); // renamed to tr because you need to have only one row, both for the header and the data
        var th = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));
        th.innerHTML = date;

        groupedAppointments[date].forEach((appointment) => {

            //*var tr = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr')); --> cell and table hadder are in the same row
            //var rowHeader = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th'))
            var cell = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
            //rowHeader.innerHTML = appointment.SlotName;
            cell.innerHTML = appointment.AppointmentDateTime;
            cell.addEventListener('click', (function(el, appointment) {
                return function() {
                    callback(el, appointment);
                }
            })(cell, appointment), false);
        })

    })

    return grid;
}
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: This was my original solution. It puts each date on a row, he wants the date to be a column.